# How to restore global environment in RStudio

Tags: r, global, environment

I am new to R and had a lot of data in global environment that I unfortunately did not save. Now that I am re-opening R, it is opening in safe mode and not re-loading my global environment. Is there a way to recover everything in my prior global environment?

Comment: When R saves the global environment it will store everything in an `.RData` file on exit. If that file exists, you can manually load it with `load()`. It should either be in your home directory or the last directory R was started from. But if that file wasn't created when you last exited R, there is no way to recover a previous global environment.

Comment: I understand. Luckily I was able to recover it. Thank you!